# Possible to resolve host name to an internal IP address from a central location?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, amazon-route53

I currently have the following setup:

- An internal server that has a web application running on it (ip
  addresss 10.1.1.47)
- Amazon Route 53 for DNS

I would like users on my internal network to be able to access the application running on the internal server using a specific url, lets call say `test.admin.mysite.com`

Currently I can setup the `/etc/hosts` file on my local OSx machine with an entry like `10.1.1.47 test.admin.mysite.com` and it will work, but I would rather not have to set this on every machine on the network.  I assume that since I am using Route 53 for DNS, that I cannot direct urls to an internal IP address.

Is it possible to have `test.admin.mysite.com` resolve to `10.1.1.47` by configuring something in a single location?

I do very little network admin tasks, so I apologize if the answer is obvious or if I have left something out.

Comment: Do you have a router with DNS which you could use, or a spare machine?  My thoughts would be to have a DNS internally on your network to point to **test.admin.mysite.com**.

Comment: You definitely need to set this up internally in your network. While it might work in some cases if you use Amazon Route 53, the chances are better it won’t.  And since the 10.x.x.x range is an internal network address there could be confusion if your clients connect to a non-office network since 10.1.1.47 cane be used by other intranets for other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to set that zone `test.admin.mysite.com` up in whatever DNS server your internal clients use, and create an `A` record in it pointing to `10.1.1.47`.  This will force your internal DNS server to believe it is authoritative for that zone and won't use external DNS (your Route 53 zones) to resolve it.

If you don't have an internal DNS server for your internal clients, (i.e. your clients go direct out to external DNS servers such as google's 8.8.8.8), you would need to configure some device as an internal DNS server first.  This would involve more than just setting up the DNS server, as you'd also have to set it up to forward to an external DNS server, as well as tell your clients to go to the internal server.

If you are using `Active Directory` a good place to create the `test.admin.mysite.com` zone would be on your AD DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your network administrator and ask him to add the name  "test.admin.mysite.com" and resolve it to your ip on which the application is running.

this is similar to adding an entry in your host file. But adding in the DNS home routs the requests in the network level for any computer that is trying to access this url from your internal network.